# Force reload overlayfs's upperdir for container

Tags: linux, kernel, containerd

I have the following issue -
I have a container, and an external application running on the node which should write files to the upperdir path of the container on the node (I am not able to write to `/proc/<pid>/root` of the container process)

so, while the container is running, the application is creating a new folder in the container's upperdir. The issue is that the container is not reloading the upperdir and because of that the new folder is not visible inside the container.

The solution that I found for now is -
`echo 3 > /proc/sys/vm/drop_caches`
which resets the Kernel caches and then the upperdir is reloaded and everything works.

The problem with this command is that it causes some downtime of the container, the container is not responding during the time the command is running, which is unacceptable for me.

Does someone know another solution which will not cause a downtime of the container?